# Erro de validação no update do Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Segue o código:

```
public function update(Request $request, Contact $contact)
{

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required|min:6|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:contacts,' . $contact->id
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $errors = $validator->errors();

        return response()->json($errors, 400);
    }

    $contact->update($request->all());

    return response()->json($contact);
}
```

> Url: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/contacts/1`
>
> Método: `PUT -> Body -> x-www-form-urlencoded`

Erro:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column "1" does not exist
>   LINE 1: select count(*) as aggregate from "contacts" where "1" = $1
>                                                              ^ (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from "contacts" where "1" = joaodasilva@email.com) in file C:\Users\Free\Documents\AppImobiliaria\api-rest\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php on line 669

Estou usando a versão `6.11.0` do Laravel e banco `Postgresql`.

Comment: Coloca o trecho onde está a query, por favor.

Comment: Por que você concatenou o validador de email com o id???

Comment: Estou utilizando esta video-aula: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nojjKw3ZmRc&list=PLwQZAwVAR7tMF5YTeD9mAN8LGqdcA55Ns&index=10

Comment: Cola o codigo da sua model contact junto a pergunta

Comment: A sua tabela `contacts` não tem a coluna `1`, você está errando na hora de gerar a validação. `'unique:contacts,' . $contact->id` vai buscar em uma coluna específica. Dê uma lida em https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A validação unique recebe parametros em ordem... primeiro a tabela, segundo a coluna e terceiro o id que deve ser ignorado.

```
'email' => "required|email|unique:contacts,email,$contact->id"
```